# Create new columns lopping an array inside mutate (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dummy data frame called **df**:

```
A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3 C1 C2 C3
1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3
```

and I would like to sum columns that contain the same letter into a new column (naming it using the corresponding letter).

I would expect this result:

```
A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3 C1 C2 C3 A B C
1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3  3 6 9
```

I know I can achieve this result using `mutate`from `dyplr`:

```
mutate(df,
       A = A1 + A2 + A3,
       B = B1 + B2 + B3,
       C = C1 + C2 + C3)
```

Is there any way to do it using a vector like `letters <- c("A", "B", "C")` and looping over that vector inside the `mutate` function? Something like:

```
mutate(df,
       letters = paste0(letters,"1") + paste0(letters,"2") + paste0(letters,"3") )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `dplyr` and `purrr` solution could be:

```
bind_cols(df, map_dfc(.x = LETTERS[1:3],
                      ~ df %>%
                       transmute(!!.x := rowSums(select(., starts_with(.x))))))

  A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3 C1 C2 C3 A B C
1  1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3 3 6 9
```

Comment: Why do you have to use !! before the first .x and not before the second one? (I have tried and if I remove the !! the new columns would be named .x, .x1and .x2 respectevely. If I add !! before the second .x nothing changes. Weird)